# Why httpd container exits immediately without any error in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. My Dockerfile (got from a tutorial) is:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apache2 \
                        libapache2-mod-jk
VOLUME ["/var/log/apache2"]
RUN echo 'ServerName localhost' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I gave `docker build -t mg:httpd apache\`. No errors.

```
λ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED                SIZE
mg                  httpd               262d7a4f85fc        About an hour ago      248MB
```

`docker run -it mg:httpd`

No errors, but the cursor returns to command prompt immediately. Getting `Unable to connect` on taking `http://localhost/` in browser.

```
λ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                
600231bbd461        mg:httpd            "apache2ctl -D FOR..."   2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago
```

docker logs is empty

```
λ docker events
2017-09-08T15:26:10.726720800+05:30 container create 5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157 (image=mg:httpd, name=zealous_ritchie)
2017-09-08T15:26:10.740310700+05:30 container attach 5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157 (image=mg:httpd, name=zealous_ritchie)
2017-09-08T15:26:11.035777100+05:30 network connect 2b8829b336575a2aa2210f55105d793e8f1b196d51845d38d3dc8ff322af6143 (container=5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2017-09-08T15:26:11.090873500+05:30 volume mount e8421cbd867fca04f0dd3ee6da815c59cad5fc32c5a427710d144213b43caa26 (container=5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157, destination=/var/log/apache2, driver=local, propagation=, read/write=true)
2017-09-08T15:26:11.548736900+05:30 container start 5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157 (image=mg:httpd, name=zealous_ritchie)
2017-09-08T15:26:11.573272300+05:30 container resize 5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157 (height=41, image=mg:httpd, name=zealous_ritchie, width=168)
2017-09-08T15:26:12.733164900+05:30 container die 5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157 (exitCode=0, image=mg:httpd, name=zealous_ritchie)
2017-09-08T15:26:13.227455500+05:30 network disconnect 2b8829b336575a2aa2210f55105d793e8f1b196d51845d38d3dc8ff322af6143 (container=5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157, name=bridge, type=bridge)
2017-09-08T15:26:13.306885700+05:30 volume unmount e8421cbd867fca04f0dd3ee6da815c59cad5fc32c5a427710d144213b43caa26 (container=5325b79abe1988312952629165551c169a8bdc3fbe6e473cf0177859db7c0157, driver=local)
```

what could be the reason?   How can I look into the apache log\conf files when the container is not started?

Comment: post `docker logs 600231` and `docker events`, it seems your container exited immediately

Answer (score 3):

So your Webserver is not startet as a foreground process, that is why the container is stopped immediately.

I think you should change

```
ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

to

```
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Because you want that command to run when the container is mounted.

The `ENTRYPOINT` directive declares the executable which is used to execute the `CMD`.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
results in:
$  apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND <command either from the run command line or the CMD directive>
```

The [default command](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/a2573609340194bf33712c1fa2dc4de8f9b70ca2/xenial/Dockerfile#L47) from Ubuntu image I could find is `/bin/bash`.
So when you run the container using:

```
docker run -it mg:httpd
```

the resulting command that is executed will be:

```
$  apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND /bin/bash
```

what obviously does not make much sense. I would recommend to go over [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) post, it explains the details very well.

After the change described above it will look like that:

```
(default) ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
what results in:
$  /bin/sh -c "apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND"
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you run the container interactively because that allows the `SIGWINCH` signal to be forwarded from the host to the container. `SIGWINCH` is used by Apache to signal a graceful shutdown. I provided a full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48273882/3634032).